# Why is ThreadPool.SetMinThreads not changing the minimum value?

Tags: c#, performance, threadpool

Compiling and running with the .NET 4.0 runtime, I have code like this:

```
int MinWorkerThreads, MaxWorkerThreads;
int MinCompletionPortThreads, MaxCompletionPortThreads;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out MinWorkerThreads, out MinCompletionPortThreads);
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out MaxWorkerThreads, out MaxCompletionPortThreads);
_logger.Info("Default thread pool settings min/max:");
_logger.Info("Worker thread: " + MinWorkerThreads + " / " + MaxWorkerThreads);
_logger.Info("IO thread    : " + MinCompletionPortThreads + " / " + MaxCompletionPortThreads);
_logger.Info("Setting minimum default worker thread count to " + Config.MinWorkerThreads);
if (!ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Config.MinWorkerThreads, MinCompletionPortThreads))
{
    _logger.Warn("Unable to modify the minimum number of worker threads");
}
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out MinWorkerThreads, out MinCompletionPortThreads);
_logger.Info("Worker thread: " + MinWorkerThreads + " / " + MaxWorkerThreads);
```

and my logging output looks like this:

```
Default thread pool settings min/max:
Worker thread: 4 / 32767
IO thread    : 4 / 1000
Setting minimum default worker thread count to 50
Worker thread: 50 / 32767
```

The value is immediately changed, but not permanently.

Why am I doing this?  `Timer`s use the default ThreadPool and I've seen times where a sudden batch of tasks entered the system thread pool, swamping it, causing some timers that are supposed to trigger every 15 seconds to be delayed by over 60 seconds.

The problem is that when I dump the same information fifteen minutes into runtime, using the same code, I get very different values:

```
Worker thread: 4 / 400
IO thread    : 4 / 400
```

Is there a better way to resolve this problem without abandoning the use of `System.Timers.Timer`?  What would reset this value in a standalone C# application that does not involve IIS at all?  If you are self-hosting ASP.NET, will that implicitly change the tuning of the system thread pool?

Comment: [This is about 3.5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976898/en-us) but perhaps related...

Comment: I did find that bug about .NET 3.5, but there the issue involves the asynchronous I/O threads, not the worker threads.  Thanks, though.

Comment: ASP.NET is significant.  What's it called again, "recycling the application pool?"  That will of course reset the threadpool as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest an alternative approach.

Eliminate **all** blocking code from the ThreadPool. That is not what it is designed for.

If you have IO-bound operations, go asynchronous at every stage.

If you have CPU-bound operations, do not run them in ThreadPool threads.

By rigidly following these rules, you should never need to fiddle with ThreadPool parameters. As you have noticed, there are too many .Net APIs that absolutely rely upon a responsive ThreadPool. If you're just gobbling up threads, it's quite likely that however many you choose, if you run your program long/hard enough, you'll hit the limit again.

Use the ThreadPool as it was intended... short lived logic, mainly for marshalling IO results to the right place.

Comment: If I had the ability, I would do exactly as you say.  It is unfortunately that .NET uses a single ThreadPool for an entire application and that all timer threads operate out of this thread pool.  I don't believe any code in this application explicitly uses the thread pool.  All (or almost all) use is implicit, such as via Timers.

Comment: @Eddie: Sure. I wonder two things then... (a) what kinds of workload are you consuming in your timer callbacks (b) which kind of Timer are you using (which namespace is it in)?

Comment: The Timer callbacks do different things.  The critical ones here make SOAP calls that are expected to be timely (+/- a dozen seconds or so).  The timer is an instance of `System.Timers.Timer()`.  Since essentially all system thread pool use is implicit, I am honestly not certain about the full set of uses it is put to.  The ASP.NET self-hosting makes use of that thread pool, right?  If there was a way to make certain timers use a private thread pool, that would be superior.